# Web Service ‘mandatory/optional’ fields: XSD Design time vs Runtime

Tags: web-services, design-patterns, soap, xsd, soa

We are currently building a pile of SOAP Web Service to front the access of various backend systems.

While defining our Request/Response message XML, we see multiple services needing the ‘Account’ object with different ‘mandatory/optional’ fields.

How should we define and enforce the validation of these ‘mandatory/optional’ fields on the same Message? I see these options

#### 1)  Enforce validation with XSD by creating different 'Account' Complexe Type

Pros : Design time clarity.

Cons : proliferation of Object Type, Less reuse of Object,

#### 2)  Enforce validation with XSD by Extending+Restriction a single base 'Account' type

Pros : Design time clarity.

Cons : Not sure of the support of the Extend+Restriction feature (java, .Net)

#### 3)  Using a single 'Account' type and enforcing validation in runtime (ie in the Code).

Pros: Simple

Cons: No design time validation. Need to communicate field requirements via a specification doc.

What are you’re thoughts on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have to assume that: i) some of what you would call optional fields are actually fields that are not applicable (don't make sense) to all accounts and ii) we're not talking trivial scenarios (like two type of accounts with 2 fields each-kind of thing).

Firstly, I would say that unless you're really lucky, from a requirements perspective, then you're going to end up with some sort of "validation in runtime" no matter what option you're going with. XML Schema can't express some common data validation requirements, such as cross field validation; or simply because the data in your XML is not sufficient to feed the rules to validate the integrity of the message (the data in the message being a subset on what's available at the time the XML is being un/marshalled).

Secondly, I would avoid deriving new complex types through restricton; from an authoring perspective you don't achieve much in terms of reuse, and you might end up with problems in how that is interpreted by your XSD to code tooling. I like to think that the original intention of deriving through restriction was to provide a tool for people to use in xsd:redefine scenarios; for people that wouldn't want to fiddle with XML Schemas that were authored by someone else. If one owns (authors) the schema, one can work around the need to restrict by defining the "lesser" object first and *extend* from that.

As to the "proliferation of objects", you are kind of getting that with option #2 as well (when compared with #1); what I mean by that, all the tools I know will create a class for each named (global) complex type you have in your XSD; so if you have to have three type of accounts, you'll have three for scenario #1, and four, or so, if you choose to extend from one, or so, base classes; a worst case scenario for the later would be when you need three specializations (concrete if you wish); anyway, from my experience, the difference in real life scenarios is not something that would really tip the decision one way or the other.

Extending base types in XML Schema is good for reuse; however, reuse brings coupling; if you're analysing this from a forward/backward compatibility point of view, extending something in the base type could mess up some of the unmarshalling (deserialization) of the XML for clients of your service(s) that don't want to change their code base, yet you want to maintain only one Web Service endpoint for all; in this case, a forward-compatibility strategy that relies on an xsd:any at the end of a compositor (xsd:sequence) would be rendered useless in your first release that goes and extends your base type.

There is even more; because of this, I don't think there's a correct answer, just for the criteria you seem to imply by setting your pro/cons.

All of my preferred options below assume that you put high value on the requirement to ensure forward/backward compatibility of your services, and you want to minimize the cost of your clients having to deal with your services (because of XML Schema changes).

I would say that if all your domain (accounts in particular) can be **fully** modeled (assume no future change basically) **and** that there is enough commonality to justify reuse, then go with option #2. Otherwise, go with option #1 since I have yet to see things that don't change...

If the modeling of your domain can be done 80% or more (or some number that you think is high) **and** that there is enough commonality to justify reuse, then I would still go with option #2, with the caveat that any future extensions for common attributes across accounts, must be applied for each individual account (basically turning your option into a hybrid, by doing #1).

For anything else, I would go #1. Whew, I can't believe I wrote all of this...

Comment: Hello Petru    
  
  
I am surprise of the selection of option 1 over option 3. Java API’s, unlike WebService with XSD, does not provide any mechanism to enforce mandatory/optional fields on a method signature and Objects. Yet, all API on the market are using javadoc to describe how to properly pass parameters to an operation.

Comment: As I said, for anything but trivial, you'll most likely end up with some sort of validation in your code - so part of #3 should be there no matter what. As an example, think of a scenario where account data is provided by the client for an update service. From my experience, option 1 gives you most control within the constraints of the XSD language where full analysis cannot be typically done upfront. What works for OO and evolving APIs, doesn't for XSD when bound to OO (XSD to Java/C#, etc.).