# XSD with version control on attribute with skip behavior

Tags: xml, xsd

I want to be able to version control my XML file.  I want an older xsd file to be able to validate newer versions of the XML file received.

To do this I will protect unknown xml tag with version attributes.

The question: how do I get the xsd to skip part of the XML based on a version attribute?  In the example below I want the xsd to be able to validate any tags with version 1 and 2 but not 3.

The scenario:

```
    <MYXML>
    <SOME_XML version="1">
        <SOME_VERSION_1_DATA>this_is_data_only_for_version_1</SOME_VERSION_1_DATA>
    </SOME_XML>
    <SOME_XML version="2">
        <SOME_VERSION_2_DATA>this_is_data_only_for_version_2</SOME_VERSION_2_DATA>
    </SOME_XML>
    <SOME_XML version="3">
        <SOME_VERSION_3_DATA>this_is_data_only_for_version_3</SOME_VERSION_3_DATA>
    </SOME_XML>
</MYXML>


<xs:complexType name="SOME_XML">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SOME_VERSION_1_DATA" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SOME_VERSION_2_DATA" type="xs:string"/>
   </xs:sequence>
   <xs:attribute ref="version"/>
 </xs:complexType>

 <xs:attribute name="version">
   <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
       <xs:enumeration value="1"/>
       <xs:enumeration value="2"/>
     </xs:restriction>
     <xs:anyAttribute processContents="skip"/>  <-- SKIP the attribute if NOT 1 ro 2?
   </xs:simpleType>
</xs:attribute>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to directly answer your problem, the use of skipping specific details from the XML.
 If it's possible in your environment, I suggest [xslt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) to transform original XML where version 3 files will be skipped, and validated XLST generated output.

XSLT to copy entire file while discarding nodes with @atribute version == 3

```
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:if test="@version != '3'">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@*|text()|comment()|processing-instruction()">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

note, XSLT written as is, it wasn't tested for given input.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use attributes for this since attributes cannot "alter" content models. If you think about making your application that is processing XML in a "forward compatible" way (i.e. use old XSDs for new content), then I would rather use a mandatory version element, followed by an optional xsd:any - all mixed with some design rules.

To make a long story short, you will need this kind of setup to be able to handle the unique particle attribution constraint (or in other words, the constraint that a parser cannot look ahead to figure out "where" it is in the XSD).

Initially you can even start without a mandatory version tag, just stick an optional xsd:any where your extensibility "place" is. As subsequent versions refine content, you may have to add this mandatory version marker (again, to deal with UPA), followed by refined content, followed again by optional xsd:any.

In general, there are other things to consider as well, such as using type extensions/restrictions in your XSD and the impact it may have on forward compatibility schemes such as the one I've just described above (please read [this on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8278921/web-service-mandatory-optional-fields-xsd-design-time-vs-runtime/8283258#8283258)).